# How to dynamically bind a color to each object in a collection?

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to change the background color like 1st row would be black while 2nd row would be white and it would continue in the same sequence

```
<template>
  <div
    v-for="(activity, index) in logActivities"
    :key="index"
    class="row bg-black"
  >
    <div class="col-6 padding-10">{{ activity.activity }}</div>
    <div class="col-6 padding-10">
      {{ toGetRelativeTime(activity.createdAt) }}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Please do not use `:key="index"`, it's doing the opposite of what it is supposed to do.

Comment: Oh, you meant alternating between black and white.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way with checking if index is even or odd:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#demo",
  data() {
    return {
      logActivities: [{activity: 'aa', createdAt: 1}, {activity: 'bb', createdAt: 2}, {activity: 'cc', createdAt: 3}, {activity: 'dd', createdAt: 4}, {activity: 'ee', createdAt: 5}]
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.bg-black {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
.bg-white {
  background: white;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <div
    v-for="(activity, index) in logActivities"
    :key="index"
    :class="index % 2 === 0 ? 'bg-black' : 'bg-white'"
    >
    <div>{{ activity.activity }}</div>
    <div>
    {{ activity.createdAt }}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please do not recommend using `:key="index"`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation yet to comment on kissu's answer, but I want to add that when using Tailwind (supposing you're using it) you can also do something like this:

```html
<template>
  <div
    v-for="(activity, index) in logActivities"
    :key="index"
    class="row odd:bg-black even:bg-white"
  >
    <div class="col-6 padding-10">{{ activity.activity }}</div>
    <div class="col-6 padding-10">
      {{ toGetRelativeTime(activity.createdAt) }}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

This will add black background for odd rows, and white background for even rows.

You can check this out on Tailwind documentation [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#first-last-odd-and-even)

Comment: For me, it's wasn't one or the other but since this is what OP wants, yeah this is a far better solution overall. Still, no index for the `:key`.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that you're using Tailwind, you can do the following

```html
<template>
  <section class="flex flex-col">
    <div
      v-for="activity in activities"
      :key="activity.id"
      :style="`background-color: ${activity.color}`"
    >
      {{ activity.name }}
    </div>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      activities: [
        { id: 1, color: 'yellow', name: 'activity 1' },
        { id: 2, color: 'orange', name: 'activity 2' },
        { id: 3, color: 'salmon', name: 'activity 3' },
      ],
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

This is how it looks

[image]